# How Do You Build An Angular Project With A Specific Environment File And Output Directory?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm attempting to add a script to my package.json file so that I can build my Angular 5 project utilizing a specific environment file and specific output directory, however the CLI always builds it to the local project repository. Here's my entry in my package.json file:

```
"ng build dev": "ng build --env=dev2 --op=X:/Project/dist"
```

When I take out the environment flag, the CLI will correctly produce the files to the output directory listed above, yet I can't seem to force it to use a specific environment file as listed in my .angular-cli.json file:

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev2": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
    "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

I'm using Angular CLI version 1.5.5. Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you try `--e` or `--environment` instead of `--env`?